# How to publish node.js web application with localhost mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, web

I have an important question.

I made a node.js API project that is connected with MongoDB in localhost. Also this API is going to work for my react native project. I want to publish on internet and get url address. Main problem is about localhost database.

Does the database connection problem occur when I publish the web application? if it does, what should i do?

I am expecting your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/database to publish your database, or if you want to just use for a few moments you can create a tunnel from your port running mongodb using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (one free tunnel per port per user) to open your connection world wide. Notice that if you choose the second option your mongodb service needs to be running (ngrok as well) as long as you want to use your application, and when connecting to your database you need to pass the ngrok generated url instead of "localhost".